# Ways to send $scope to be used into prototype functions

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope

I'm trying to figure out ways to let the `$scope` available to access from my prototype methods:

Sending `$scope` as a parameter:

```
var myController = function($scope, Service) {
    $scope.myMethod = function() {
        this.myMethod($scope);
    }
} 
myController.prototype.myMethod = function($scope) {
    // accessing the variables trhough the parameter.
}
```

Adding a reference to `$scope` into the controller itself.

```
var myController = function($scope, Service) {
    this.scope = $scope;
    $scope.myMethod = function() {
        this.myMethod();
    }
}
myController.prototype.myMethod = function() {
    // accessing the variables through this.scope
}
```

Is there another pratices or ways or better approaches to access the `$scope` inside prototype functions?

Comment: Javascript is not an object-oriented language, it's a functional language - trying to replicate OOP objects and inheritance isn't really  the best-practice way to go about writing JS. I'm not saying you can't, but you'd probably find it easier to implement a solution with callbacks and closures easier than a bodged OOP implementation :-)

Answer (score 0):

You are not supposed to play with controllers like that.

You've already define your method - myMethod inside of controller as

```
$scope.myMethod = function(){...}
```

and this method has access to all of the $scope properties.

I do not see a point of doing this? Could you elaborate on why you need this ?

Otherwise, you'll have to pass $scope as a method parameter which completely would break the modular, scope based paradigm angular is based on.